# Export Powershell output to CSV

Tags: powershell, recursion, foreach, export-to-csv

I have the following code intended to take a list of user names and output a CSV report of username - GroupMembership. At the command line the output looks great as i get "name" on the left and recursive "group memberships" on the right (see pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLxUR.jpg for command line output, sorry can't post imbedded Pics yet)

I would like to have the output written to a CSV file with the same format, namely Username in one column and GroupMemberships in the second column.. Original code from: http://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/03/21/get-a-users-group-memberships/ with a few small changes.

```
Param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeLine=$true)]
   [Alias("ID","Users")]
   [string[]]$User
)
Begin {
   Try { Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop }
   Catch { Write-Host "Unable to load Active Directory module, is RSAT installed?"; Break }
}

Process {
    ForEach ($U in $User)
   {  $UN = Get-ADUser $U -Properties MemberOf
      $Groups = ForEach ($Group in ($UN.MemberOf))
      {   (Get-ADGroup $Group).Name
      }
      $Groups = $Groups | Sort
      ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
      {  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Name = $UN.Name
            Group = $Group
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried using this "$PSObject | Export-CSV C:\Scripts\GroupMembershipList.csv" but it only writes the first line to the CSV and nothing after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nate,

In Powershell v3.0, the Export-CSV cmdlet introduced the -Append parameter.

#### Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx

Not knowing the version of Powershell you are using, this may require an update on your side to make use of the new functionality.

In my own cases, I generally see the opposite issue if I forget to -Append to my CSV; I will only end up with the **LAST** entry as opposed to just the first.

I won't claim this to be your fix, but might be worth a shot...

Example: `$PSObject | Export-CSV C:\Scripts\GroupMembershipList.csv -Append`

Comment: Jason, that did it sir, thank you very much! Tried to upvote and mark as answer but my reputation isn't high enough.